# setValue after iteration in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am attempting to create a script that searches another sheet for related data, based on the value entered in a range of cells.  then inputs the corresponding data in the appropriate adjacent cell.  I can get as far as pulling the correct data, but then I cannot get it to set the values in the right cells on my sheet.  Am I missing something?

Thanks for any assistance

```
function attend() {
  var otherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("blahblah").getSheetByName("Students");
  var range = otherSheet.getRange("A1:M100");
  var students = range.getValues();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("blahblah2").getSheetByName("Attendance");
  var range2 = ss.getRange("B7:D27");
  var students2 = range2.getValues();
  var range3 = ss.getRange("E7:E27");
  var classPack = range3.getValues();
  for (var u = 0; u < students2.length; u++){
   for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  if (students2[u][0] == "x") {
    if (students[i][0] == "x") {
      if (students[i][10] > 0){
      var data = students[i][10]; 
       students2[u][4] = data;
       range3.setValues(classPack);
} 

  }
}
   }
  }

}
```

Modified Code

```
function onEdit() {
  var otherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("blahblah").getSheetByName("Students")
  var range = otherSheet.getRange("A1:M100")
  var students = range.getValues()
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("blahblah2").getSheetByName("Attendance")
  var range2 = ss.getRange("B7:G27")
  var students2 = range2.getValues()
  for (var u = 0; u < students2.length; u++){
  if (students2[u][0] == "x") {
    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
      if (students[i][0] == "x") {
      var classPack = students[i][10]
      var membership = students[i][7]
      var free = students[i][8]
       students2[u][3] = classPack;
       students2[u][4] = membership;
       students2[u][5] = free;
       range2.setValues(students2);
} 

  }

  }

  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading range3 from ss2, then getValues() from range3 (classpack), but then you are writing back to the same range with the same values (classpack), in the last statement.  So there is nothing else being written to the sheet.

Also, I don't think you can have students2[u][4] since the students2 values came from the range "B7:D27", which are only 3 columns wide, so there can only be a maximum of students2[u][2].

I modified your script, as below, to get something written to the column E in case it helps you with your script. Perhaps you could give a bit more info as to what you want written into column E (and did you mean to get information/data from classPack, or simply to write to that range).

```
function attend() {
  var otherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AvhOXv5OGFq6dGlGT0lxb2t5MUh5S0ZscXBKeU0tTFE").getSheetByName("Students");
  var range = otherSheet.getRange("A1:M100");
  var students = range.getValues();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AvhOXv5OGFq6dEhFajY5R1VWNHp6bzdTZVNGaHlXX3c").getSheetByName("Attendance");
  var range2 = ss.getRange("B7:D27");
  var students2 = range2.getValues();
  //var range3 = ss.getRange("E7:E27");
  //var classPack = range3.getValues();
  for (var u = 0; u < students2.length; u++){
    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
      if (students2[u][0] == students[i][0]) {
        if (students[i][0]> 0) {
          var data = students[i][10]; 
          ss.getRange("E"+ (7+u)).setValue(data);
//          students2[u][4] = data;
//          range3.setValues(classPack);
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Pls note that I haven't used/referred to classPack nor range3, so it could well not be what you want.

Comment: LOl I just figured it out on my own but you hit it right on the head.  Thanks.  My modified code is added above